# ImportError: No module named kivy

Tags: python, import, module, kivy, python-3.4

I am new to Ubuntu and Python. Basically I installed kivy just as the website told me to do.First I built the repo

```
     $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
```

Then I do the apt

```
     sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

Ok now I fire up Geany and follow the websites instructions to do the infamous "Hello World" then when I run in the program directory ~/Documents/Kivy for me

```
    python helloWorld
```

Here is the code for the app

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

I immediately get the error

```
    File "~/Documents/Kivy/helloWorld", line 1, in <module>
import kivy
```

Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show the outputs of the apt-get command run and the complete error?

Comment: Maybe you're trying to run the code with Python 2.7 after you installed libraries for Python 3. Check `python --version` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that the apt install is:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

That will install kivy for python3... not python 2

Instead of running:

```
python helloWorld
```

Try typing:

```
python3 helloWorld
```

Answer (score 1):

For any noobs like myself looking to get this going on MAC OSX and totally confused, this is from the Kivy site:

"You can run any Kivy application by simply dragging the application’s main file onto the Kivy.app icon."

Answer (score 0):

After adding the ppa, you should do "sudo apt-get update" to make sure that the package is installed.

Also it is important you run it with "python3" instead of "python" which is generally the older version. kivy you downloaded is a python3 version and doesn't get imported by legacy 2.7 python.

I got it running with

```
python3 helloworld.py
```

Comment: I am glad to know this solution worked for you... Please mark this post as answered